# Enforce ProxySettingsPerUser=0 without open administrator's systemsettings panel

Tags: command-line, proxy, windows-registry, administrator, runas

I would like to use ProxySettingsPerUser=0 to (remotely) configure machines to use system wide the administrator user proxy configuration.

I can deploy registry settings remotely but I noticed that to activate ProxySettingsPerUser=0 I need to open ms-settings:network-proxy from the administrator user after I set the registry. Even the reboot doesn't make the magic.

Right know I'm deploying this registry changes:

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxySettingsPerUser /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoDetect /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoDetect /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

I'm doing something incorrectly?

I don't have Active Directory, so no GPO.
I launch commands as administrator to the remote clients by GLPI.

I tryed to launch "ms-settings:network-proxy" from GLPI in the target machine but even if it opens the settings panel it does not activate the behavior like when I open it manually from the administrator profile.

Comment: I think you're missing entering the following command in a CMD run as administrator: `netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie` ([link](https://help.zerto.com/en-US/kb/000003313))

Comment: Worked! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing finishing touch for the poster was to run the command:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie
```

Reference :
[How to set the proxy settings for all users when Cannot see Analytics data](https://help.zerto.com/en-US/kb/000003313).

Comment: Once set I tested that I can change it remotely with:
SavedLegacySettings and DefaultConnectionSettings
in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections